# Windows 10 - Display backlight randomly and automatically turns off, only turns back on when the keyboard 'turn-off display' button is pressed

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, lcd, backlight

I'm having this problem for quite a while now. The backlight of the display of my laptop, a Lenovo [Yoga 500-14IBD](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-500-14ibd/documentation), running Windows (10 Home 1909), randomly shuts off. The behaviour is similar to the 'turn off display' button present on the keyboard (it turns the backlight off while the LCD works normally - I have confirmed this by placing the flashlight of my phone behind the glass panel and I can see things that are normally displayed). 
External display works fine.

When the backlight turns off randomly, I have to press the 'turn off display' button the keyboard twice, to turn it back on - only to shut itself off again, sometimes immediately.

I have determined that it is a Windows based problem based on two things.

1. This only happens when Windows has loaded and/or is running. It does not happen when I am in the BIOS setup screen.
2. ~The person at the hardware repair shop said that they tried recreating the problem on Ubuntu live, and it didn't happen.~(PLEASE SEE EDIT)

So the problem is Windows based, but I can't seem to find any solution for it. Here's what I have tried so far -

1. Tried to extend the screen turn off time on Windows settings
2. Tried to turn off the setting 'Do not do anything when the lid is closed' as I suspected that since my lid is broken, the reed switch might be a foul player

But to no avail whatsoever. Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated. Please request if any more information is needed.

EDIT - I tested by running Ubuntu 16.04 Live and the problem was recreated. Display randomly shutting off and turns off by pressing the said button twice. 
Lenovo Vantage reports that the BIOS is up-to-date.

Comment: BIOS version? https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-500-14ibd/solutions/ht070218 Please update if not up to date https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500008 If that doesn't resolve, get  Kubuntu's ISO https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu then make a LiveUSB https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows, boot with it, to confirm shop's right by running w/ it for a while before backing up yr data & reinstall Windows

Comment: I avidly hope someone else has a better answer.

Comment: I updated based on your suggestions @K7AAY